Can packaged_task<void()> type objects be stored in queue?
This is the code for submitting tasks in the thread pool that I implemented, which is used to submit tasks to the thread pool. tasks_ is the task queue. This is the modified code.
using Task = std::function<void()>;
std::queue<Task> tasks_;

   
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto ThreadPool::submitTask(F &&f, Args &&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
    using RetType = decltype(f(args...));
    auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<RetType()> >(
        std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    std::future<RetType> res = task->get_future();
    //

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!notFullCondition_.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1),
                                        [&] { return taskSize_.load() < taskQueueThreshold_; })) {
            std::cerr << "ThreadPool::submitTask() failed" << std::endl;
            std::packaged_task<RetType()> emptytask([] { return RetType(); });
            auto ret = emptytask.get_future();
            emptytask();
            return ret;
        }
        tasks_.emplace([=] { (*task)(); });
        ++taskSize_;

        notEmptyCondition_.notify_all();
    }
    
    return res;
}

Initially, I did not use shared_ptr to encapsulate the packaged_task<> function object, but directly passed the packaged_task<> object into the lambda expression and then saved it in queue<function<void()>> tasks_ object. However, function must require that the function passed in is copy-constructible, so I changed it to queue<packaged_task<void()>> task_, and did not modify the rest. That is, the following code runs without any problems. However, when I asked this question on Claude, it did not recommend doing so. I attached its answer at the bottom of the question. So can I use queue<packaged_task<void()>> task_ as my task queue?
using Task = std::packaged_task<void()>;
std::queue<Task> tasks_;

template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto ThreadPool::submitTask(F &&f, Args &&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
    using RetType = decltype(f(args...));

    std::packaged_task<RetType()> task(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    std::future<RetType> res = task.get_future();
    //

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!notFullCondition_.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1),
                                        [&] { return taskSize_.load() < taskQueueThreshold_; })) {
            std::cerr << "ThreadPool::submitTask() failed" << std::endl;
            std::packaged_task<RetType()> emptytask([] { return RetType(); });
            auto ret = emptytask.get_future();
            emptytask();
            return ret;
        }
        tasks_.emplace([task=std::move(task)] mutable { task(); });
        ++taskSize_;

        notEmptyCondition_.notify_all();
    }
    
    return res;
}

Here's why changing the task queue type to packaged_task won't work:
The idea might not work because std::packaged_task itself is non-copyable. If you change the task queue type to std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> or something similar, you'll encounter the same issue when adding tasks to the queue because the queue needs to copy its elements internally.
In other words, you'll just be moving from a "non-copyable lambda" problem to a "non-copyable packaged_task" problem.
Better solutions would be:

Either use shared_ptr to wrap the packaged_task as discussed earlier
Or modify the task queue implementation to use a copyable alternative, like:
std::queue<std::shared_ptr<std::packaged_task<void()>>> tasks_;



The first approach is more elegant as it maintains the original std::function interface while only adjusting the internal implementation. This is why I recommended this solution earlier.
Would you like me to explain why packaged_task was designed to be non-copyable in the first place?


why packaged_task was designed to be non-copyable

Internally, packaged_task must hold a promise. These cannot be copied. Hence, the packaged_task cannot be copied, either.
Think of it what it would mean for the holder of the future if the packaged_task were copied. Would it receive a result twice when both copies of the packaged_task were executed? That does not make sense and is outside of its design.
And if somehow a second future would become available, how would one get hold of it, and which of the copies would the original future refer to?

When I add a task to the task queue, I use the queue's emplace function. Doesn't this process involve move construction? And other threads will only execute tasks once when they get them from the task queue. So, I should be able to set the task queue to the queue<packaged_task<void()>> type.

The general rule is to require the least properties from your type erasure as you reasonably can.
std::packaged_task is move-only because it has a shared resource with the futures it produces.  Classes with an identity like that don't like being duplicated; what does it mean when a packaged_task with a shared state is duplicated?  Do you get 2 packaged tasks with the same shared state?  If you invoke them both, what happens?
To not have to worry about that problem it was made move-only.
As it happens, a packaged_task stores a callable.  Because the packaged_task is move-only, it only requires its callable to be move-only.
packaged_task<R(Args...)> is a callable with signature void(Args...) and can store a callable with signature R(Args...).  This somewhat confusingly means you can store a packaged_task<R(Args)> within a packaged_task<void(Args...)>; the future the inner packaged_task provides is distinct from the one the outer void packaged_task provides.
MVCS has a bug in that its std::packaged_task requires its contained invocable be copyable.
As it happens, c++23 has added std::move_only_function.  This gives you what you really want; packaged_task<void(Args...)> was always a bit heavyweight (as it has its shared state synchronized with a future) for a move-only callable.  You can also build your own; writing a std::function-like is a bit of a rite of passage.
Going over your code, a C++23 solution would look like:
template<class R, class...Args>
std::future<R> make_ready_future( Args&&... args ) {
  std::packaged_task<R(Args&&...)> makerTask(
    [](Args&&...args)->R { return R(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
  );
  auto ret = makerTask.get_future();
  makerTask(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return ret;
}
using Task = std::move_only_function<void()>;
std::queue<Task> tasks_;

template<class F, class... Args, class R=std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, Args...>>>
auto ThreadPool::submitTask(F &&f, Args &&... args) -> std::future<R>
{
  std::packaged_task<R()> task(
    [f=std::forward<F>(f), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()mutable
    -> R
    {
      return std::apply( std::move(f), std::move(args) );
    }
  );
  std::future<R> res = task->get_future();

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (!notFullCondition_.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1),
                                        [&] { return tasks_.size() < taskQueueThreshold_; }))
    {
      std::cerr << "ThreadPool::submitTask() failed" << std::endl;
      return make_ready_future<R>();
    } else {
      tasks_.emplace(std::move(task));
    }    
     notEmptyCondition_.notify_all();
  }
    
  return res;
}


you can have std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>>, queues can hold move-only types, you just have 2 problems.

you are storing a packaged_task inside another packaged_task, and packaged_task is not copyable, just do tasks_.emplace(std::move(task));
on MSVC the callable of packaged_task needs to be copyable ,see bug report, you can get around this by allocating the lambda on the heap with make_shared, this is apperantly not needed for libstdc++ and libc++

auto func_generator = [&]()
        {
            return std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
using callable_type = decltype(func_generator());
std::packaged_task<RetType()> task{ [call_obj = std::make_shared<callable_type>(func_generator())] { (*call_obj)(); } };

godbolt example
a possible optimization is to only allocate it on the heap if the original lambda wasn't copyable, with std::is_copy_constructible
auto func_generator = [&]()
        {
            return std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
using callable_type = decltype(func_generator());
std::packaged_task<RetType()> task;
if constexpr (std::is_copy_constructible_v<callable_type>)
{
    task = std::packaged_task<RetType()>{ func_generator() };
}
else
{
    task = std::packaged_task<RetType()>{ [call_obj = std::make_shared<callable_type>(func_generator())] { (*call_obj)(); } };
}

godbolt example
the use of func_generator is dual purpose, it simplifies getting the callable_type, and it invokes mandatory RVO.

the other option is to rewrite std::packaged_task using std::promise and std::move_only_function so it can store move-only callables, or just use mingw instead of MSVC on windows, which doesn't have this bug, and can store move only callables in std::packaged_task

Why does the callable of a packaged task need to be copyable?  I believe that is false; which makes most of your answer a wild goose chase.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont  MSVC standard library requires packaged_task lambda to be copyable ... godbolt example looks like libstdc++ and libc++ don't

apperantly that's a 10 year old bug in MSVC, that they just decided not to fix, because it will break ABI.

so his code would have compiled on gcc, but he got that error because he was using MSVC, so this goose chase wasn't pointless :)

HOOOONNNNKKKKKKKK
